# Clone failed: unable to access 'http://username:password@47.92.35.46:1010/r/MyRepo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git

when I clone from rep, I meet this problem:

```
Clone failed: 
unable to access 'http://username:password@47.92.35.46:1010/r/MyRepo.git/': 
The requested URL returned error: 403;
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would ask an admin of the server to check the log of the HTTP listener (Apache? NGiNX? other tool?)

That way, said admin can see if:

- your git query was seen,
- the authentication worked (meaning you used the right password)
- and if the path was accessible by your username.

Note that if the password has any special characters, there would need to be [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters).

Comment: 3Q you ，I will try